# Proj4leaflet in UTM 32

Tags: r, coordinate-system, leaflet, utm, leaflet-r

I am trying to create a simple map in UTM32 (EPSG:25832) in R with leaflet and proj4leaflet, but I can't get it to work. I found a url for the basemap, but it could be a different one if you like - I don't really know how to find one.

```
library(leaflet)
leaflet(
  options =
    leafletOptions(
      worldCopyJump = FALSE,
      crs=leafletCRS(
    crsClass="L.Proj.CRS",
    code='EPSG:25832',
    proj4def='+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs',
    resolutions = 0.00028*c(
      17471320.7509, 8735660.37545, 4367830.18772, 2183915.09386, 1091957.54693, 545978.773466, 272989.386733, 136494.693366, 68247.3466832, 34123.6733416, 17061.8366708, 8530.9183354, 4265.4591677, 2132.72958385 ),
    origin =c(0.105946948013, 56.8478734515))
)) %>%
  addTiles(
urlTemplate = 'http://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/wmts_webatlasde/tile/1.0.0/webatlasde/default/DE_EPSG_25832_ADV/{z}/{y}/{x}.png',
options = tileOptions(minZoom=0,maxZoom=14,continuousWorld = TRUE)) %>%
  setView(lng = 12.526906, lat = 55.680339, zoom = 14)
```

I am not quite sure how to set the resolution and origin either.

The example [here](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/blob/master/inst/examples/proj4Leaflet.R) for UTM33 is working fine.

Comment: Still haven't figured this out. Hope someone can help.